# Relation between infinite series and integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration

Is there any relation between the definite integral and infinite series  excluding the fact that  an improper integral can be viewed as an infinite series whose terms are definite integrals? By definition, the definite integral is somewhat similar to an infinite series as it is a sum of infinite amount of terms.

Comment: In measure theory, sums may be interpreted as integrals over the integers with respect to a discrete measure; whereas integrals as we commonly think of them are with respect to the so-called *Lebesgue measure*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as thyde641 points out, infinite series (or, more generally, any sums) can be viewed as integrals if one knows about the more general idea of integration with respect to a measure.  If you want further details, look up "measure theory".